# To Share Data Directly or Make Copies

Tags: database, copy, data-modeling, shared

This is a very simple description of a complex system.  The below stores and services have tons of relationships and millions of records of various types.  Plus it is used by several applications.

I have a project that consists of a bunch of stores that contains lots of services.  This is simple relation.  Most of these services do not change much.  But many times new stores are created by copying an existing store which requires copying all of the services.

A client wanted stores to support parent companies.  So a parent company can have one or more stores.  This is mainly for reporting purposes and does not affect the relationship with stores and services.  This is done and not big deal.

Now we have a client saying, they want the parent company to be able to create services and push them to specific stores.  But because stores are located all over the world, each service needs to have its own pricing (there are also inventory considerations).
On the surface there are two basic approaches.  First we can have one parent company service record that is shared amongst stores and provide a different DB structure to hold pricing for each store.   The main problem with this is each application now needs to supply ID of the service and the store ID to ensure it is reading the proper service data.  For regular loads and searches requires an additional table join which adds more db overhead.

The second solution we can create a copy of the parent companies service record to each store.  So no new DB entity need be created (except for a few references to the parent company).   All code can run as normal w/o knowledge of the changes.  This will necessitate a synchronization service to ensure whenever a parent company level service changes, all stores are updated.  Additionally any new stores added to the parent company needs to have the shared services added.

From a normalization standpoint, the first solution seems best.  But from maintenance the second is easier to implement and requires less changes to how services are handled.  However sync process is a potential point of failure, but it should not be used very often.

So what is the consensus with the two approaches?